# Memory keeps growing but no leaks reported

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an app that's very memory intensive...LOTS of image processing in Core Graphics routines and custom pixel processing routines.

I've been very careful with memory as far as I can tell, but the longer my app runs, I notice memory slowing rising in the Memory Report in Xcode 5. I've run it many times in Instruments and I don't see any leaks.

Any ideas on how to debug this or where I can look?

Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't aware that instruments tells you whenever there's a leak. As far as I know it's meant to show you what is using memory and let you pair up related references so you can identify where the leak is happening.

Comment: @jraede, but valgrind does. I guess, it's worth a shoot.

Comment: @jraede the Leaks tool in Instruments does.

Comment: Not all memory waste are leaks. There are also retain cycles and objects with references well past their usefulness.

Comment: Wait are you telling me that I have spent hours pairing up references and I could have just clicked on the "leaks" tool??

Comment: @jraede Keep in mind that memory leaks is not the same thing as reference cycles. ARC code rarely has leaks but it is quite common to have reference cycles. Reference cycles are much harder to find and fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use instruments to see what is getting allocated and to look at the retain/release/autorelease lifecycle of an image and what the call stack is for each of them.

If you have memory growing without leaks you are still holding onto the memory somewhere.

Comment: The real answer was to get to know the Allocations instrument. This blog was very helpful as well: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

Comment: And so was the WWDC 2010 video on Advanced Memory Analysis with Instruments https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=311 even though it's a little dated and pre-ARC...still very helpful.